# MinGW Compiler Errors - How do I setup the MSYS bat?

Tags: c++, mingw, msys

I'm running **Windows 8**.

I installed the MinGW compiler to the default C:\ directory using the *GUI installer*. I selected to install all the elements available in the *Basic Setup* package of the *MinGW Installation Manager*.

After the installation completed, I checked that "C:/MinGW/msys/1.0/etc/fstab" had the one line of `C:/MinGW /mingw` and an open line beneath it. I also created a shortcut to *msys.bat* in the Start menu.

Then I rebooted my machine.

I created a folder called *"CompileBin"* in the C:\ directory, so `C:\CompileBin\` and then I placed my *test.cpp* file inside, so `C:\CompileBin\test.cpp`

I ran *msys.bat* and the console opened up. It showed:

```
MyName,@MyLaptopsName ~
$
```

I started to navigate to where my *test.cpp* is:

```
cd c:\CompileBin\
```

Now the prompt looked like this:

```
MyName,@MyLaptopsName ~
$ cd c:\CompileBin\
>
```

I entered the `dir` command to look around and got the response:

```
MyName,@MyLaptopsName ~
$ cd c:\CompileBin\
> dir
sh: cd: c:CompileBindir: No such file or directory
```

Okay, so I figured maybe the path wasn't set up.

I added `PATH` to the *Environment Variables* (because it was NOT originally there) and gave it the value `C:\MinGW\bin;`

I still get the same error.

Comment: NOTE! I added a user `PATH` variable `C:\MinGW\bin\` - I did not change the system `Path` variable, as per the installation instructions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unix tooling requires forward slashes in path names.  It is `cd c:/CompileBin`

Comment: Should I delete the question?